# Expected value of this deceptively simple variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Setting: $X \overset{d}{\sim} \pmb{U}[-1,1]$ and 
$$\begin{align*}&Y = |X|\\[0.4cm]&
Z = \begin{cases}\dfrac{X}{|X|}, & \text{ if } X \neq 0,\\[0.2cm] 0,&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}\end{align*}$$

Find $\pmb{E}[Y]$, $\pmb{E}[Z]$ and $\pmb{E}[YZ]$.

---

**Edit:** And how would you check if they're independent? One statement I could check is
$$\Pr\{Y \le y, Z \le z\} = \Pr\{Y \le y\}\Pr\{Z \le z\}$$
By definition, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{y} \int_{-\infty}^{z} f_{YZ}(y,z) dy dz \quad \text{ on LHS and } \quad \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{Y}(y) dy \int_{-\infty}^{z} f_{Z}(z) dz$$ on the RHS.

But I am having trouble proceeding.

Note: Per suggestions, I changed my wording to better reflect the fact that they may or may not be independent.

Comment: To find $E(Z)$: note that $Z$ is either 1, 0, or -1.   With what probability does it take each of those values?

Comment: Why do you suppose they are not independent? See eg $P(Y \le y)=P(Y \le y | Z =z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Ε[Y]=Ε|Χ|=\int_{-1}^{1}|x|f_X(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{0}-x\frac12dx+\int_{0}^{1}x\frac12dx=\not 2\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot\frac1{\not2}dx=\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_{0}^{1}=\frac12$$ and since $P(Z=0)=P(X=0)=0$: $$E[Z]=E\left[\frac{X}{|X|}\right]=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{x}{-x}\frac12dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x}\frac12dx=-\int_{-1}^{0}\frac12dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac12dx=0$$
and $$E[YZ]=E\left[|X|\cdot\frac{X}{|X|}\right]=E[X]=0$$

---

**To your edit:** So, by the above $$E[YZ]=0=0\cdot\frac12=E[Y]E[Z]$$ which means that $Y,Z$ are uncorrelated. To see that they are also independent, observe that $Z$ is a discrete random variable that takes with positive probability only the values $1$ and $-1$. That is, the pmf of $Z$ is $$P(Z=-1)=P(Z=1)=\frac12$$ Now, ask the question: *Does the knowledge of $Z$ affect the probability that $Y\le y$ for some $y \in (0,1)$?* i.e. does the following equality hold or not: $$P(Y\le y)\overset{?}=P(Y\le y \mid Z=z)$$ where $z\in \{-1,1\}$, $y\in (0,1)$. Indeed for $z=-1$: $$\begin{align*}P(Y\le y \mid Z=-1)&=\frac{P(Y \le y, Z=-1)}{P(Z=-1)}=\frac{P(|X| \le y, X<0)}{P(X<0)}=\frac{P(-y\le X<0)}{\frac12}\\[0.2cm]&=2P(-y\le X<0)=^{\text{symmetry of }X} \\[0.2cm]&=P(-y\le X <0)+P(0<X\le y)\\[0.2cm]&=P(-y \le X \le y)=P(|X|\le y)=P(Y\le y)\end{align*}$$ Similarly you can proceed if $z=1$, which means that knowing the value of $Z$ does "not help you" to infer something about $Y$. Thus, by the above $$P(Y\le y, Z=z)=P(Y\le y \mid Z=z)P(Z=z)=P(Y\le y)P(Z=z)$$ for all $y\in(0,1)$ and $z=\pm1$. (For other values of $y$ and $z$ the conclusion is immediate).

Comment: Y is uniform on (0,1) and E(Y) is 1/4? (And an upvote...)

Comment: Sorry @Stef I updated the question after you answered it already, since I didn't want to ask a new question with the same setting

Comment: @chibro2 Are you asked to prove that they are not independent, or to check whether they are independent or not?

Comment: Check they're independent or not. I guessed that they should not be independent, but I could be wrong...